# How to remove all roles at once (Discord.py 1.4.1)

Tags: python-3.x, command, discord, discord.py, roles

I try to make a command which would add "Prisoner" role, and remove all roles the targeted user has

```
    @commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
    async def prison(self, ctx, member: discord.Member):
        """Imprison offender"""
        role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='Prisoner')
        await member.add_roles(role)
        await member.remove_roles()
        await ctx.message.add_reaction(emoji=self.tick)
        await ctx.send(f"{member} is imprisoned!")

    @prison.error
    async def prison_error(ctx, error):
      if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send("Sorry you're not allowed to use this command. This command is only for the Server's authorities.")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the "Prisoner" roles before deleting every roles. Try the other way around

```py
    @commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
    async def prison(self, ctx, member: discord.Member):
        """Imprison offender"""
        role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='Prisoner')
        await member.remove_roles(member.roles) # remove all member roles before
        await member.add_roles(role) # then add the new role
        await ctx.message.add_reaction(emoji=self.tick)
        await ctx.send(f"{member} is imprisoned!")
```

Comment: I try yours way but now it show error `discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10011): Unknown Role` although the role exist.

Comment: Also it doesn't remove all roles.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I have been fighting with the same problem but I think I got a solution:

```
@bot.command()
async def ban(ctx , member: discord.Member):
   guild = ctx.guild
   members_roles = member.roles
  
   for i in range(len(members_roles)-1):
       await member.remove_roles(members_roles[i+1])
   
   
   role_id = <id of the role "prisoner" in your case>
   role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, id=role_id)
   await member.add_roles(role)
```

You have to have the -1 and +1 in the for loop
because the bot cannot do anything with @everyone
Witch is a default role with the index of 0
Thats why you have been getting the Error