# discord.py trying to remove all roles from a user

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a problem that I`m trying to remove all roles a user has for some kind of mute role but it gives me this error `discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10011): Unknown Role`

Here`s my code

```
@client.command(aliases=['m'])
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members = True)
async def mute(ctx,member : discord.Member):
    muteRole = ctx.guild.get_role(728203394673672333)
    for i in member.roles:
        await member.remove_roles(i)
    await member.add_roles(muteRole)
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit = 1)
    await ctx.send(str(member)+' has been muted!')
```

I know that this kind of questiion was alredy asked here: [How to remove all roles at once (Discord.py 1.4.1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63536983/how-to-remove-all-roles-at-once-discord-py-1-4-1).
But it wasn`t answered and did not help me at all

Comment: As It says "Unknown Role" I think the problem is with `muteRole = ctx.guild.get_role(728203394673672333)`. I suggest you try to get the role with the name of it like `muteRole = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name='rolename')`.

Comment: the muteRole variable has no impact on the cycle it is used for adding not removing also it worked before i added ```for i in member.roles:
        await member.remove_roles(i)``` cycle

Comment: According to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63536983/how-to-remove-all-roles-at-once-discord-py-1-4-1). You can use `await member.remove_roles(member.roles)` to remove all roles from the user. Maybe you can try that out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that all users have an "invisible role", `@everyone`. You will see it show up if you try

```py
for i in member.roles:
    print(i)
```

`remove_roles` is a high level function and it will try to remove `@everyone`, which is causing your error.

To clear all current roles from the user, you can do:

```py
@client.command(aliases=['m'])
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members = True)
async def mute(ctx, member : discord.Member):
    muteRole = ctx.guild.get_role(775449115022589982)
    await member.edit(roles=[muteRole]) # Replaces all current roles with roles in list
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit = 1)
    await ctx.send(str(member)+' has been muted!')
```

`await member.edit(roles=[])` Replaces all the current roles with the roles you have in the list. Leave the list empty to remove all roles from the user.

[discord.Member.edit](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.edit)

Although if you want to do it with a `for loop`, you can use `try`

```py
@client.command(aliases=['m'])
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members = True)
async def mute(ctx, member : discord.Member):
    muteRole = ctx.guild.get_role(775449115022589982)
    for i in member.roles:
        try:
            await member.remove_roles(i)
        except:
            print(f"Can't remove the role {i}")
    await member.add_roles(muteRole)
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit = 1)
    await ctx.send(str(member)+' has been muted!')
```

Comment: that worked but now it gives me the ```discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions``` error although I am the server owner and have a role that has literaly all permissions

Comment: @Double The missing permission is for the bot, if you check server settings and roles, make sure the bot is placed at the top. It can only make changes to roles that are lower than itself in that list of roles.