# Removing every role from a user discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I wanna do a ban appeal system on my server. I wanna remove every single role of someone and give them the `[Banned]` role. I cannot just do something like I did for the member role for all of them since there are a lot of roles, even some custom ones that are made and deleted every day.

```
member_role = get(user.guild.roles, name="『✅』· ")
await user.remove_roles(member_role, reason=None, atomic=True)
```

I tried this: [discord.py trying to remove all roles from a user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65416388/discord-py-trying-to-remove-all-roles-from-a-user) but it didn't work. Also tried this:

```
for role in user.roles:
    if role.name == '[Banned]':
        pass
    else:
        await user.remove_roles(role)
```

but couldn't get it to work. (I have no experience in python or discord.py)

So. How can I remove every role from a user instead of only the `member_role` ?

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def ban(ctx, user: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
  await asyncio.sleep(1)
  banned_role = get(user.guild.roles, name="[Banned]")
  await user.add_roles(banned_role, reason=None, atomic=True)
  member_role = get(user.guild.roles, name="『✅』· ")
  await user.remove_roles(member_role, reason=None, atomic=True)
  banemb = discord.Embed(title="Ban", description=f"{user.mention} a fost banat/a. ", colour=discord.Colour.dark_red())
  banemb.add_field(name="Motiv:", value=reason, inline=False)
  await ctx.send(embed=banemb)
```

Comment: If you have no idea about Python or `discord.py`, then I would read the docs or watch tutorials first. If one would explain something to you now, then you would not understand it at all?

Comment: I started a week ago and i can do some things..i can say that i have a somehow good bot with a lot of utilities. But i am stuck at this softbanning for a day and i can't get around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get the list of roles that way.

To remove all the roles of the user you have to apply an `edit` to it and provide an empty list of roles.

It also changes the order of your code as you first have to remove and then re-assign a role to the user.

**Have a look at the following code:**

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def ban(ctx, user: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    banned_role = discord.utils.get(user.guild.roles, name="[Banned]")
    await user.edit(roles=[]) # Remove all roles
    await user.add_roles(banned_role, reason=None) # Assign the new role
    banemb = discord.Embed(title="Ban", description=f"{user.mention} a fost banat/a. ",
                           colour=discord.Colour.dark_red())
    banemb.add_field(name="Motiv:", value=reason, inline=False)
    await ctx.send(embed=banemb)
```

*I have changed/removed a few things from the code. Of course you have to add them again, according to your wishes.*