# Discord.py remove all roles command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, command, bots

I made a remove all roles command but when I use it the bot says I don't have permission to remove roles When it does what do i do

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_roles=True)
async def strip(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    try:
        await member.edit(roles=[])
        await ctx.send(f"All roles have been removed from {member.display_name}.")
    except discord.Forbidden:
        await ctx.send("I don't have permission to remove roles.")
    except discord.HTTPException:
        await ctx.send("Failed to remove roles.")
```

Comment: It looks like `except discord.Forbidden` is triggered here. Make sure that the bot role is **above** all the roles you want to remove.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The problem is when you use `member.edit` then set the roles list to nothing, than your command tries to remove all roles from a member includeing @everyone.

So I have two solutions for you:
First:

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_roles=True)
async def strip(ctx:commands.Context,member:discord.Member):
    try:
        for i in member.roles:
            try:
                await member.remove_roles(i)
            except:
                print(f"Can't remove the role {i}")
        await ctx.send(f"Roles have been removed from {member.mention}")
    except discord.Forbidden:
        await ctx.send("You don't have permission")
    except discord.HTTPException:
        await ctx.send("Command failed")
```

Second (similar to yours):

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_roles=True)
async def strip2(ctx:commands.Context, member: discord.Member):
    everyone = ctx.guild.default_role
    try:
        await member.edit(roles=[everyone])
        await ctx.send(f"All roles have been removed from {member.display_name}.")
    except discord.Forbidden:
        await ctx.send("I don't have permission to remove roles.")
    except discord.HTTPException:
        await ctx.send("Failed to remove roles.")
```

In the second method if you try it on a bot it wont work, because bots have roles assigned to them which you can't remove.
What you should do then is to define that role like this:

```
guild=ctx.guild
role = guild.get_role(ROLE_ID)
```

Then paste in the role to the list after or before `everyone`:

```
await member.edit(roles=[everyone,role]
```

Be aware, because if you leave it like this it will assign the bots role to any member you use the command on, so do this only while testing than remove the `role` from the list!

Comment: The `everyone` role is not a real role at all as it's not present when you open a member profile. OP said "*but when I use it the bot says I don't have permission to remove roles*" so it must be something else. `await member.edit(roles=[])` simply removes all roles, which is valid.

Comment: I tried the command before I wrote the answer (I always do and have a bot dedicated to this) and if you give it `everyone` it works in discord.py 2.3.0 or higher.

Comment: You're not unassigning the `everyone` role in this case. It technically can't be removed, not even manually. It's more related to role hierarchy in this case.

Comment: You are right about hierarchy but both `member.edit` and `member.remove_roles()` is trying to remove invisible roles such as @everyone and automatically created bot roles.
Anyways the first command I provided prints out the roles that the bot can not remove which in my case are: @everyone, @Easy (my other bots automatic role), and Owner which is higher then the bots role itself. So you are half correct.

Comment: The method is **not** trying to remove invisible roles, that simply is not possible (*Copy the ID of the “everyone role” and try to ping it as a normal role. The result will be `@@everyone`*). There are three methods to remove roles: `await member.remove_roles(role_1, role_2, role_3, ...)`, `await member.remove_roles(*member.roles)` or `await member.edit(roles=[])`. All will just remove the roles assigned.

Comment: Okay... I can't say anything to that. Just try the first command I provided and see which roles can not be removed. You will see @everyone in the terminal. And it is because if you go to the roles section you will se the role `@everyone` and it is assigned to members. I did some research and found this in an old stack post: **`remove_roles` is a high level function and it will try to remove @everyone** Here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65416388/discord-py-trying-to-remove-all-roles-from-a-user

That's all I can say...

Comment: Yes ty the 2nd one worked perfectly 1 question is possible to add an exception for 1 role which is named members?

Comment: Yes! You can define guild:
`guild=ctx.guild`
Then you define the role:
`role=guild.get_role(ROLE_ID)`

And you add the `role` variable to your list:
`await member.edit(roles=[everyone,role])`

That's it. If you need anything my discord is in my profile. Easier to talk there :D
Also if my answer helped it would be grate if you would accept it as a solution so the question will not appear as unanswered!